# How to find max and min values in different groups in Excel data using R

Tags: r, excel, sorting, max, min

I am new to R, but need to write a code to find the max and min values on each date, and then have it create new columns that give the max/min values and which hour of the day they are associated with.

Here is an example of the data set:

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z85ih.png)
(I can separate the date and time to two columns if it would make it easier)

```
5/11/2022 12:00:00 AM   -2.081698896
5/11/2022 01:00:00 AM   -3.485276263
5/11/2022 02:00:00 AM   -1.53921172
5/11/2022 03:00:00 AM   -0.971277113
5/11/2022 04:00:00 AM   1.087641775
5/11/2022 05:00:00 AM   1.532685864
5/11/2022 06:00:00 AM   -0.279100848
5/11/2022 07:00:00 AM   -2.110513273
5/11/2022 08:00:00 AM   -1.450939087
5/11/2022 09:00:00 AM   -0.756648162
5/11/2022 10:00:00 AM   0.101390372
5/11/2022 11:00:00 AM   0.961030453
5/11/2022 12:00:00 PM   0.531307116
5/11/2022 01:00:00 PM   1.151855083
5/11/2022 02:00:00 PM   1.768739844
5/11/2022 03:00:00 PM   1.233669468
5/11/2022 04:00:00 PM   1.491899352
5/11/2022 05:00:00 PM   1.144093768
5/11/2022 06:00:00 PM   2.160505945
5/11/2022 07:00:00 PM   1.795628853
5/11/2022 08:00:00 PM   4.531107262
5/11/2022 09:00:00 PM   3.62462192
5/11/2022 10:00:00 PM   1.286594924
5/11/2022 11:00:00 PM   -3.791104623
5/12/2022 12:00:00 AM   0.622076737
5/12/2022 01:00:00 AM   0.090568132
5/12/2022 02:00:00 AM   1.59146776
5/12/2022 03:00:00 AM   -0.479784099
5/12/2022 04:00:00 AM   0.489422285
5/12/2022 05:00:00 AM   0.073997738
5/12/2022 06:00:00 AM   -0.010696904
5/12/2022 07:00:00 AM   -2.632483198
5/12/2022 08:00:00 AM   -1.461297052
5/12/2022 09:00:00 AM   -1.522490002
5/12/2022 10:00:00 AM   -0.940460749
5/12/2022 11:00:00 AM   -0.374553431
5/12/2022 12:00:00 PM   0.062439221
5/12/2022 01:00:00 PM   0.400666873
5/12/2022 02:00:00 PM   1.051929106
5/12/2022 03:00:00 PM   1.179060269
5/12/2022 04:00:00 PM   0.946240502
5/12/2022 05:00:00 PM   1.962386886
5/12/2022 06:00:00 PM   2.171089482
5/12/2022 07:00:00 PM   3.622429106
5/12/2022 08:00:00 PM   3.741439222
5/12/2022 09:00:00 PM   -1.805726046
5/12/2022 10:00:00 PM   -4.234257479
5/12/2022 11:00:00 PM   -4.779267306
5/13/2022 12:00:00 AM   -5.588944721
5/13/2022 01:00:00 AM   -5.716968341
5/13/2022 02:00:00 AM   -3.641873457
5/13/2022 03:00:00 AM   -1.483733735
5/13/2022 04:00:00 AM   -1.173960641
5/13/2022 05:00:00 AM   -0.858666579
5/13/2022 06:00:00 AM   -1.341592707
5/13/2022 07:00:00 AM   -2.641237393
5/13/2022 08:00:00 AM   -2.739222797
5/13/2022 09:00:00 AM   -0.892693229
5/13/2022 10:00:00 AM   -0.157481635
5/13/2022 11:00:00 AM   0.904515563
5/13/2022 12:00:00 PM   1.000066424
5/13/2022 01:00:00 PM   1.354307836
5/13/2022 02:00:00 PM   1.625249928
5/13/2022 03:00:00 PM   2.155380173
5/13/2022 04:00:00 PM   2.025535026
5/13/2022 05:00:00 PM   2.246808707
5/13/2022 06:00:00 PM   2.95513702
5/13/2022 07:00:00 PM   3.222890919
5/13/2022 08:00:00 PM   3.235698828
5/13/2022 09:00:00 PM   0.862131896
5/13/2022 10:00:00 PM   -1.258192244
5/13/2022 11:00:00 PM   0.040982598
```

So, with this code the output would hopefully create a new column that looked something like this:

max:

```
5/11/2022  8:00PM  2.683375,
5/12/2022  7:00PM  1.9246,
5/13/2022  7:00PM  1.83976,
```

and then have something similar for the minimum values.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Comment: Please share data as copy/pasteable text, not a picture. We can't test or demonstrate solutions on a picture. `dput()` is great for making copy/pasteable R code to reproduce data - `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` will make code to reproduce the first 5 rows of `your_data`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I added the data as text, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Load the required libraries
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Read the Excel file
your_data <- read_excel("data.xlsx")

# Convert the date and time column to POSIXct format
your_data$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(your_data$Date, format = "%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S")

# Extract date and hour components
your_data$DateOnly <- as.Date(your_data$DateTime)
your_data$Hour <- format(your_data$DateTime, "%H")

# Group by date and hour, then summarize to find max and min values
result <- your_data %>%
  group_by(DateOnly, Hour) %>%
  summarize(max_value = max(values),
            min_value = min(values))

# Merge the result back to the original dataset
your_data <- your_data %>%
  left_join(result, by = c("DateOnly", "Hour"))

# Print the modified dataset
print(your_data)
```